# Method to select matching data elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm new to jQuery and have a question that goes beyond my knowledge. I have a link with a unique data-number and a div with a matching data-number. The goal is to hide all divs and when each link is clicked by the user the div would be displayed with the matching data-number.

The part that's difficult for me to figure out is how to iterate through all of the links and divs matching them up so when each link is clicked ONLY the matching div with the same data-number will be displayed.

Here is what I have so far in Coffeescript:

```
    $('#task-item').on('click', (event) ->
    n = $(@).data('number')
    if (n > 0)
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#task-info').fadeToggle(600)
    )
```

Sample html link:

```
<li id="task-item" data-number="3">
   <span class="label label-purple"> Task</span>
     <i class="icon-angle-right"></i> 
       <span class="label label-success">Open</span> 
         <a href="#" id="task-desc">NEW SAVE METHOD FOR TASKS</a> 
    ..... additional HTML....
</li>
```

Sample div html:

```
<div id="task-info" data-number="3" class="span8">
  ..... #MORE HTML HERE ....
</div>
```

If there is a better way to accomplish this I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have more than one `LI` with `id="task-item"`? IDs must be unique, you should be using classes instead.

Comment: HTML `id should be unique in the page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I assume the `li` and `div` in your example are repeated multiple times, so you should be using a `class` to identify them. Secondly, you can use `filter` to find the element by the required data attribute. Try this:

```
$('.task-item').on('click', (event) ->
    var $item = $(this);
    $('.task-info').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('number') == $item.data('number');
    }).fadeToggle(600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery attribute selectors

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

You should be able to select the div you want like this:

```
$("div[data-value='3']")
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would recommend is change the `li` ids to class like `<li class="task-item">`

Then

```
<div class="task-info" data-number="3" class="span8">
```

JS

```
$(".task-item").click(function(e){

  var itemNumber=$(this).data('number');
  $('.task-info').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('number') == itemNumber
  }).fadeToggle(600);

});
```